# PHP/MySQL insert into multiple data tables on submit

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm building a web application in work and I have a form where users can register certain types of information.

```
Username   |   Password   |   Company
```

Now I'm unsure how to approach this. What I want is when the user submits that registration form Username, password and company get written to one data table(user) BUT because Company, in the user data table, is a foreign key reference I need Company to be written to a separate datatable(company) as a Primary Key (and of course username to be written as a FK reference as its a 1 - 1 relationship).

I'm not looking for a coded solution from you guys because I know my PHP and MYSQL I'm just looking for some pseudo code algorithms to get the creative juices flowing!

EDIT: I AM USING POSTGRESQL not MYSQL but I'm pretty sure there's little difference except port numbers and small syntax changes

Comment: There is a big difference between MySQL and Postgres. With the latter you can solve this in one step with data-modifying CTE - as demonstrated under [your follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12095553/939860).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume first column is `id`:

1. Save Company `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO company VALUES (NULL, '$company_name')";`
2. Get id of this item. `$company_id = $mysqli->insert_id;`
3. Save User with this id `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password', '$company_id')";`
4. Get user's id `$user_id = $mysqli->insert_id;`
5. Update the company with it: `$mysqli->query("UPDATE company SET user_id = $user_id WHERE company_id = $company_id)";`

Comment: Sorry, a company has only ONE user because that user is a member of staff at the company providing information about their company. Regardless of the details is a 1..1 relationship both ways.

Comment: what would be the PostGreSQL syntax? Is $mysqli the handle on the theoretical database?

Comment: anyway my solution will work. but if you also need save `user_id` in `company` table you need get user id which was created at step 3, and update `company` table with this id

Comment: @DanielD question was about mysql. I guess postgre has similar methods. $mysqli is mysql specific - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Okay thank you, the algorithm seems to make sense will look up the PSGQL equivalent but thank you =]

Comment: Would it possible for you to edit your answer with the next algorithm for inserting the new USER_ID into the Company table? I will then accept this answer as correct.

Comment: thank you I'm doing a million things today! Can't figure anything out! Will accept your answer as correct and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Begin to insert your compagny in your table compagny.
Get back the id. (There is a sql requete like `LastInsertId`)
Insert the user/password/IdCompagny in your table user.

EDIT : some help : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: okay that's cool sorry I should've mentioned I'm using PostGreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

- why is User:Company == 1:1? If I and a coworker join your site, do we need to pretend to work at different places?
- if companies can have more than one employee, what kind of validation will you employ to combine variations on company names (e.g. IBM vs International Business Machines)?
- what if a user is unemployed?

If Company is a *nice-to-know* datum rather than a *required-or-things-break* datum, I'd probably sign up my user first. Then, when the user logs in you can nag them for additional information. This has the added advantage of making user registration less onerous for the user.

A use case:

- user submits `username` and `password`
- filtre input for bad stuff and validate for duplication, suitability
- save to db and retrieve user PK
- load 'additional info' page and set a session var as a "nag" flag
  -if user chooses not to fill out add'l info, nag flag can trigger reminder behaviour
- add autocomplete to Company field so that user can use existing Company table entries
- process form and save to db

  - either add company and associate user
  - or just associate user
- unset session nag flag so your website won't continue to nag

Comment: I can't reveal too much about the project I'm working as its a Government project but in the scenario I have been given having a 1..1 relationship works.

Comment: @DanielD fair enough.  I asked the questions because I've had that "honest, there will only ever be one" conversation too many times.  Usually several months down the road someone says "How come I can't...".  I find it's often better to design the db to allow for that, and implement the 1:1 business rule in the PHP.

Comment: yeah that's more than understandable and I completely agree just wish I could explain.