# PHP/MySQL INSERT feature logic error

Tags: php, postgresql

I recently asked a question about writing to multiple tables: [PHP/MySQL insert into multiple data tables on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672011/php-mysql-insert-into-multiple-data-tables-on-submit/11672152#comment15493725_11672152)

I have now tried out this code and there are no errors produced in the actual code but the results I am getting are strange. When a user clicks register this 'insert.php' page is called and the code can be found below.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"]; 
$institution = $_POST["institution"];

$conn = pg_connect("database connection information"); //in reality this has been filled
$result = pg_query($conn, "INSERT INTO institutions (i_id, name) VALUES (null, '$institution') RETURNING i_id");
$insert_row = pg_fetch_row($result);
$insti_id = $insert_row[0];

// INSTITUTION SAVED AND HAS ITS OWN ID BUT NO MEMBER OF STAFF ID

$resultTwo = pg_query($conn, "INSERT INTO staff VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password', '$insti_id'");
$insert_rowTwo = pg_fetch_row($resultTwo);
$user_id = $insert_rowTwo[0];
// USER SAVED WITH OWN ID AND COMPANY ID
// ASSIGN AN INSTITUTION TO A STAFF MEMBER IF THE STAFF'S $company_id MATCHES THAT OF THE
// INSTITUION IN QUESTION
$update = pg_query($conn, "UPDATE institutions SET u_id = '$user_id' WHERE i_id = '$insti_id'");  

pg_close($conn);

?>
```

What the result of this is just the browser waiting for a server response but there it just constantly waits. Almost like an infinite loop I'm assuming. There are no current errors produced so I think it may be down to a logic error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the database and see if the rows are inserted?

Comment: Done this and no they are empty

Comment: Alright, after each pg_query, add the following, replacing $result with $resultTwo and $update as needed: if($result == false) echo pg_last_error($conn);

Comment: This code tries to fetch the results of an INSERT, but an INSERT without a RETURNING has not result to fetch. Also it is not doing any error checking. On top of that, it has holes for SQL injections everywhere.

Comment: You say "MySQL", but it looks like you're using PostgreSQL?

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem I have deleted this tag after realizing my mistake.

Comment: @DanielVérité this is still in the testing stage and I will be implemented sufficient error checking and protection against SQL Injections

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis I have implemented the if statements and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors:

- `RETURNING` clause is missing in the second `INSERT` statement.
- Provide an explicit list of columns for your second `INSERT` statement, too.
- Don't supply `NULL` in the [`INSERT` statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) if you want the column default (serial columns?) to kick in. Use the keyword `DEFAULT` or just don't mention the column at all.

The better solution:

Use [data-moidifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), available since PostgreSQL 9.1 to do it all in one statement and save a overhead and round trips to the server. (MySQL knows nothing of the sort, not even plain CTEs).

Also, skip the `UPDATE` by re-modelling the logic. Retrieve one id with [`nextval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html), and make do with just two `INSERT` statements.

Assuming this data model (you should have supplied that in your question):

```
CREATE TABLE institutions(i_id serial, name text, u_id int);
CREATE TABLE staff(user_id serial, username text, password text, i_id int);
```

This *one* query does it all:

```
WITH x AS (
    INSERT INTO staff(username, password, i_id) -- provide column list
    VALUES ('$username', '$password', nextval('institutions_i_id_seq'))
    RETURNING user_id, i_id
    )
INSERT INTO institutions (i_id, u_id, name)
SELECT x.i_id, x.user_id, '$institution'
FROM   x
RETURNING u_id, i_id; -- if you need the values back, else you are done
```

---

#### Data model

You might think about changing your data model to a classical n:m relationship.
Would include these tables and primary keys:

```
staff (u_id serial PRIMARY KEY, ...)
institution (i_id serial PRIMARY KEY, ...)
institution_staff (i_id, u_id, ...,  PRIMARY KEY(i_id, u_id)) -- implements n:m
```

You can always define `institution_staff.i_id UNIQUE`, if a user can only belong to one `institution`.

Comment: A delayed reply but if I changed my data model would the query above still work? Because I have the data model you assumed but I have enforced referential integrity between u_id and i_id in each table so they are FK references.